# Change default time of auto-hide timer of ScrollViewer scrollbars

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

When a ScrollViewer has scrollbars showing, and the cursor is not moved for around 3 seconds, the scrollbars auto hide.

Is there a way to set that time to more or less than the default time?

**EDIT**

Reproduce so:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer Height="500" Width="500">
        <Grid Background="Blue" Height="1000" Width="1000">                
        </Grid>            
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Move the cursor over the ScrollViewer to show the scrollbar. Leave the cursor motionless for 3 seconds to see the scrollbar disappear. I want to change those 3 seconds to 1.

**EDIT 2**

Follow-up question - [Why does this ScrollViewer's ScrollBars appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467867/why-does-this-scrollviewers-scrollbars-appear-twice) .

Comment: If you go check out a [ScrollBar style template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299150.aspx) notice there's [FadeOutThemeAnimation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR210302) attached to the Vertical/HorizontalRoot's for the tracks. You can go add BeginTime/Duration to adjust the time but there's not a property exposed to do it without digging into the template.

Comment: @ChrisW. I don't know this stuff well, but all of the FadeOutThemeAnimation's seem to have a BeginTime="0" already (in your first link) , so I don't understand what can be done.

Comment: No worries. What you're looking for are the FadeIn/FadeOut theme transitions and how they're invoked for each state. For example the "NoIndicator" state has BeginTimes set to zero because as soon as No Indicator is necessary then it begins the FadeOut immediately based on its built in timing functions. As example if you were to comment out the elements of that State, then the tracks would remain visible. It does take a little practice to get used to how the VisualStateManager works. Blend is great when first learning by using the "States" tab to see how they interact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose I need to start breaking the habit of doing quickie answers in comments anyway so;

Carrying from the original comments above. The control style templates for `Scrollbar` have embedded ThemeAnimation's for FadeIn/FadeOut nested in various states in the `VisualStateManager` portion.

Being that they're [animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/animations-overview) inheriting in order of;

> Object -> DependencyObject -> Timeline

...they do support Dependency Properties such as `BeginTime` and `Duration` that allows us to alter the default behavior of their action. So to remedy your scenario you have the options of either removing them entirely from their respective states within the `VisualStateManager` or you can alter the properties to better suit your needs of your own timeline requirements.

Doing this is just a matter of extracting the control template using either VS or Blend and either applying changes explicitly to a copy of the template or overriding the default globally.

Glad you found your remedy. :)

Comment: Nothing wrong with `quickie answers in comments`. I just wanted to give you credit (-the coveted reputation points :)). Thanks again.

Comment: I thought I solved it but not. I tried doing this using this helpful answer, but as I said in the comment to the question - All Begin Times of the scrollBar are 0 already. I tried fixing this up in the ScrollViewer instead, but though I _can_ get it to hide quicker - it also ruins the scrollbar use.

Comment: I may have to see what you mean. Having trouble visualizing what you're describing.

Comment: I edited the question now to include how to reproduce the expected and desired behavior. (Thanks for your perseverance.)

Comment: It turns out I just have to edit the ScrollViewer's Template and change the values there. Thanks for setting me on the right path!

Comment: Cool! Ya sometimes the nested control structure leaves all sorts of fun for finding a culprit in the layers. Glad you got your remedy!

Comment: @ispiro Ok I'm swamped until I leave the office, I'll load it up when I get home and just fix it for ya if you haven't gotten a response by then, hadn't actually loaded up the templates yet. I'm central standard time zone.

Comment: Did you get this sorted? I didn't get back until late

Comment: According to [the comments from this one on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467867/why-does-this-scrollviewers-scrollbars-appear-twice#comment62444228_37467867) - 1.1 seconds is, by experience, the least that works. And there is no way to fix the extra time when staying on the ScrollViewer. Thanks for asking.

Comment: We'll see about that later when I have time to go poke around. ;)