# Edit xaml style

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, uwp, blend

I'm trying to edit an XAML style as suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389446/change-default-time-of-auto-hide-timer-of-scrollviewer-scrollbars#comment62350642_37389446), following [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj170032.aspx#5ebdb33f-aad2-4c10-a328-5e8b04c56a36) - but the MSDN tutorial says "To create a style, select the object, and then in the Object menu, choose Edit Style" and I can't find an object menu. The objects and timeline tab does not include an option for "edit style", and there is no "object" menu at the top of the screen.

This must be simple if you know this stuff. But I can't find it.

Comment: Ah sorry man, didn't know you were left hanging. If you just plop a Scrollbar control on your design area you can either do the Right-Click thing directly to the Scrollbar, or selecting it from the objects and timeline. If you start with ScrollViewer as opposed to Scrollbar you'll have to dig in a few layers deep to hit the Scrollbar parts. I'm going to be making videos/tutorials for this exact sort of thing as soon as I can find the free time to finish my site redesign and stuff, I know what a pain it can be on the first couple tries until you get a hang of it!

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks. I assume I can't edit its style, only its template because it doesn't give me that option.

Comment: It's template is the style :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That MSDN article is a bit outdated. To edit a style (assuming you are using Visual Studio 2013/2015 or Blend for Visual Studio 2013/2015), select the object in the XAML designer, then use Format menu -> Edit style...