# Why does this ScrollViewer's ScrollBars appear twice?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I edited a **ScrollViewer**'s template to wait only 0.5 seconds before hiding the scrollbars, and this succeeds in hiding them at that time, but they reappear for another 0.5 seconds. Why?

To reproduce, create a page resource for a ScrollViewer's Style with the default Template ([find it here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299151.aspx)) and change the 3 occurances of "3" to "0.5". Then use the following XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer Height="500" Width="500" Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}">
        <Grid Background="Blue" Height="1000" Width="1000">
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Move the cursor over the ScrollViewer to show the scrollbar. Leave the cursor motionless for 0.5 seconds to see the scrollbar disappear. It then reappears for another 0.5 seconds. Why?

Comment: check `Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}"` visual states and animations

Comment: @Stamos I guess I wasn't clear enough - `ScrollViewerControlTemplate1` _is_ the template I edited

Comment: At the last two line of your question you describe something that 99% has to do with the visualstates/Animations of that template. Can you kindly please edit your question and add the template xaml?;

Comment: @Stamos Follow the link in the question (-[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299151.aspx)).

Comment: You have to *at least* set the `KeyTime` to `1.1`s.

Comment: @JustinXL Thanks. Source? But anyway - that will only remove the 'flicker'. Staying on the ScollViewer will still show the cursor for longer than moving the cursor out of the ScrollViewer (which gives the real 1.1 seconds).

Comment: @ispiro I don't think you can have what you want using just xaml states. There must be something in code that does that hide/show. Unfortunately SV is sealed too.

Comment: @JustinXL Thanks. As for the `1.1` - is that from experience, or did you see that in some documentation?

Comment: Just from past experience. :) I tried the same thing before.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're not going to make it work, but if you REALLY think it's worth your time - you could put the `ScrollBars` in your own grids and run your own animations on the grids whenever you decide you want to do that.